# Putting a dot before decimal value in edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, decimal

I'm attempting to do something that shouldn't be trivial with an edit text. I want to be able to input a point or dot as the first entry followed by numbers but for some reason this doesn't work. If I put a zero (0) then a number it works fine. I want users to be able to enter cents into a field. Is this the default behaviour of the edit text's support for decimals? Or can this be modified on the widget itself? Or does a special formatter need to be written in order to display the values in this order.

I have the input type specified programmatically like so

```
   protected int getInputType() {
    return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED
            | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding inputType as numberDecimal|numberSigned in EditText.
It should work,

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
```

You can add inputType dynamically also,

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

Let me know if any other help required.

Comment: I can't add these to the xml because I'm generating the edit text dynamically.